# Gmail Style Always Visible Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

I am looking to implement something similar to Gmail's always visible menu. I'm not sure what the effect is called.

Is this something I can do in JavaScript? If so, can someone point me in the direction of how I can achieve this?

[image: http://gamepacks.org/1.png]

[image: http://gamepacks.org/2.png]

Comment: try make the css position of this div to fixed 'position: fixed'

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. there are some plugins that do it like:

- [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/)
- [jquery floating menu](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-floating-menu)
- [stickyfloat](http://jsbin.com/eqihef)